# Windows command to launch remote Python script

Tags: python, powershell, remote-access

I am looking for the quickest method to use one Windows command to run a remote Python script. So far, I have looked at Powershell, but it seems like I would need to use `Invoke-Command` to remotely launch a remote Powershell script, which would then launch Python script locally. Is there an easier, more direct way to do this?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Computer $remotehost -Scriptblock { python.exe 'C:\local\script.py' }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct Jon,

`Invoke-Command` is the best way to run a remote job against another machine.

As Ansgar said in the comments:
`Invoke-Command -Computer $remotehost -Scriptblock {python.exe 'C:\local\script.py'}`

Would be 100% along the lines of what you would need to do to run this remotely.

*More information can be found here:*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6

Comment: is it possible to use invoke-command to run python script in local system from powershell core

Answer (score 1):

Use `Invoke-Command` for this, it's what it was designed for.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName {
  # Assumes python.exe is on the remote $env:PATH
  # and that you are running a python file, not module
  python \path\to\file.py
}
```

As an added bonus, if you want to run this on several computers at once, `-ComputerName` lets you pass in an array of computer names as well, like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer1, computer2, computer3, computerX {
  # Assumes python.exe is on the remote $env:PATH
  # and that you are running a python file, not module
  python \path\to\file.py
}
```

[You can read more about `Invoke-Command` here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6)